# How to use a variable from another function in Python 3?

Tags: python

I'm trying to add 50 everytime the user wins but the earn variable is undefined. How do I make it defined?

```
def cash():
payment = float(input("Enter payment: "))
earn = payment
print("You entered: PHP {:.2f}".format(payment))
return earn

def game():
    ai_choice = {'0':'Rock', '1':'Paper', '2': 'Scissors'}

    def rock():
        ai = ai_choice[str(random.randint(0,2))]
        if ai == "Rock":
           output = "Tie"
        elif ai == "Scissors":
            output = "User Win"
            earn += 50
        else:
            output = "User Lose"
        output_window()
        outcome.config(text = output)
```

[image: Code and Error]

Comment: You don't seem to be calling the `cash()` function.

Comment: You can pass it as an argument to the function

Answer (score 1):

You don't, the variables in a function are internal to that function. That isolation is the whole point of the function.

Currently you aren't calling the `cash()`-function, so it's unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable in global scope, then use it in both functions

```
global_var = 'foo'

def set_golbal_var():
    global global_var
    global_var = 'bar'

def print_global_var():
    #don't need to declare as global, because it isn't being changed.
    print(global_var)

print_global_var()
set_golbal_var()
print_global_var()
```

should output

```
foo
bar
```

generally, though, this is bad practice. Usually you want to pass the variable as arguments to each function. that would look like this:

```
pass_var = 'foo'

def set_var(passed_var):
    passed_var = 'bar'
    return passed_var

def print_var(passed_var):
    print(passed_var)

print_var(pass_var)
pass_var = set_var(pass_var)
print_var(pass_var)
```

which outputs the same thing.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: btw the `global global_var` in `print_global_var()` is unecessary if you only read the variable.

Comment: Noted. For reason you mentioned I'm not well versed on the intricacies of global scope. You know what, teach a man to fish, I'll also add what should be done.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve but `earn` is not defined because it is scoped to the `cash` function. What you probably want to do is call the `cash` function returning its value to a variable somewhere before the `earn += 50` line.

So that you have `earn = cash()`. Note that this "earn" will be different from the "earn" in the cash function.

Also a side tip, doing:

```
ai_choice = {'0':'Rock', '1':'Paper', '2': 'Scissors'}
ai = ai_choice[str(random.randint(0,2))]
```

uses unnecessary datastructures and convolutes the code. A simpler alternative would be:

```
ai_choice = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
ai = ai_choice[random.randint(0,2)]
```